# Created a custom Spring boot layoutFactory and now am unable to launch my spring boot app

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot

This is the error I get -

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
```

If I takeout the layoutFactory option, I am able to launch the boot app.

In my `build.gradle` I have

```
springBoot  {
    mainClass = "com.mycompany.Application"
    layoutFactory = new CustomLayoutFactory()

}

class CustomLayoutFactory implements LayoutFactory {

    @Override
    Layout getLayout(File source) {
        if (source?.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith('.jar')) {
            return new Layouts.Jar() {
                @Override
                public String getLibraryDestination(String libraryName, LibraryScope scope) {
                    return "lib/";
                }

                @Override
                public String getRepackagedClassesLocation() {
                    return "";
                }
            };
        }

        return Layouts.forFile(source);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a custom jar layout that packages nested jars in `lib` rather than `BOOT-INF/lib`, but, as far as I can tell, you're still using Spring Boot's `JarLauncher` from Spring Boot's default loader that expects to find jars in `BOOT-INF/lib`.

You need to implement `CustomLoaderLayout` and provide your own loader classes in the root of the jar that know to look in `lib` rather than `BOOT-INF/lib`.

Comment: Thanks Andy.

I have this. What needs to change in here?

public MyClass extends Layouts.Jar implements CustomLoaderLayout {

    public void writeLoadedClasses(LoaderClassesWriter writer) throws IOException {
        writer.writeEntry(this.name, new ByteArrayInputStream("test".getBytes()));
    }

    public String getLibraryDestination(String libraryName, LibraryScope scope) {
        return "lib/";
    }

    public String getClassesLocation() {
        return "";
    }

    public String getRepackagedClassesLocation() {
        return "";
    }
}

Comment: I just need more information on defining loader classes. How do I get spring-boot to use a class I created that extends Layouts.Jar and implements CustomLoaderLayout. 

    public void writeLoadedClasses(LoaderClassesWriter writer) throws IOException {
        writer.writeLoaderClasses();
    }

    public String getLibraryDestination(String libraryName, LibraryScope scope) {
        return "lib/";
    }

    public String getClassesLocation() {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String getRepackagedClassesLocation() {
        return "";
    }